# store all the results of a loop in a single string

Tags: c#

I am trying to store the resulting strings together (combine them) into a single string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    string pedido = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this with Linq might work:

```
String.Join(",", (from a in dataGridView1.AsEnumerable() select a.Cells[2].Value.ToString()).ToList())
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use a `StringBuilder` for this rather than a `String`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i){
    sb.Append(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
 }

string pedido = sb.ToString();
```

Strings are immutable, so they cannot be changed. If you keep appending values to the same string, you may run into some performance problems creating and destroying the values all the time. `StringBuilder` will let you keep appending without all that overhead.