# String immutability and interning in .net

Tags: .net, string, string-interning

I was going to post an answer on [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290209/store-all-the-results-of-a-loop-in-a-single-string) but someone went ahead of me with the StringBuilder class, anyways, digressing...

I understand that strings in .NET are immutable, so creating a string and modifying it will actually create two different strings in memory, contrary to the `StringBuilder Class` which maintains an internal buffer and creates a final string only on the `ToString()` call. I also know that .NET interns each string, so only a copy will be created per string ever used in the application.

When you append a string to another one they are both being used in the application, so they both get interned (don't they?), the main reason for not to append strings with the concatenation operator is because you will end up with a whole bunch of strings in memory when done, each larger than the previous.

I understand that concatenating `01234` with `56789` will result in the following two strings in memory:

> 01234 
>  0123456789

whilst using the `StringBuilder` will only yield, due to interning:

> 01234 
>  56789

obviously the second approach is better for performance but, how good is it actually? I mean, if you're creating a bigger string from a small list of values, why should I consider the `StringBuilder` (that per se takes memory space)? Is it **always** good to use it? Or is there any good rule of thumbs as to when [not] to use it?

Comment: maybe double post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529999/when-to-use-stringbuilder

Comment: Not actually a duplicate but that question did clarify some stuff. Thanks.

Comment: One purpose of `StringBuilder` is to ensure that string concatenation is linear to the length of the string rather than quadratic.  You may find Eric Lippert's response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10197472) to be informative; his first basic strategy is what you get when you do not use stringbuilder.  If you prefer a lower-level discussion, Joel on Software discusses from the perspective of C in his article, [back to basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also know that .NET interns each string

No, you got the wrong idea about interning.  When you create a new string by, say, concatenating then the runtime does *not* go hunting through the table of interned strings to see if there might be a match.  That would be grossly inefficient, too many cpu cycles for a very modest savings in GC heap space.

The only strings that are interned in a regular .NET app are the ones that started out as interned from the beginning.  The ones that the compiler created from literals in your source code and added to the string table in the assembly metadata.  You can explicitly intern a string with the String.Intern() method but that's a very rare thing to do.

You use StringBuilder to avoid generating too many temporary strings that have only a very short life span.